# Trigger window.open as ajax complete

Tags: javascript, window.open

In a website there are a some jQuery ajax calls, in some of them, if success, is triggered a winwdow.open in another domain. I own the other domain sites.

For example:

1. site https://site1.example.com make on ajax call on itself
2. if success trigger a window.open on https://site1.example2.com or https://site2.example.com
3. often the popup blocker blocks the operation

How can I handle this issue? Do I have to enable CORS on my site/server https://enable-cors.org/ ?

Code (sure, I don't own google):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    complete: function (response) {
        $('#output').html(response.responseText);
        window.open('https://www.google.com');
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    },
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/nbsu3hgk/

Comment: I know, but, if possible I have to handle this without browser options or it produce some help desk on my users

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a problem like yours. In my case, I needed to perform some operations before opening a new page. 
I demanded the new page opening to the anchor tag and I used the preventDefault method to avoid the opening when the operations returned a negative result.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" targe="_blank" onclick="doSomeOperation(event)">text</a>  

<script>
function doSomeOperation(event){
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    url:'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    complete: function (response) {
        $('#output').html(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    },
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `window.open` requires direct user action (e. g. a click) to avoid popup-blockers, you could change your code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    complete: function (response) {
        $('#output').html(response.responseText);
        //window.open('https://www.google.com');
        $( "body" ).append('<button id="openPopup">Open Site</button>');
        $( "#openPopup" ).click( function() { 
                window.open('https://www.google.com');
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    },
});
```

If the ajax request is successful, users are shown a button which they have to click to get to the other domain.

**Edit:** Referring to your comment below I think I found a solution:

```
var myPopup;
$( document ).on("click", "#myButton", function() {
    myPopup = window.open("/");

    $.ajax({
        url:'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
        complete: function (response) {
            $('#output').html(response.responseText);
            //window.open('https://www.google.com');
            myPopup.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
        },
    });
});
```

You have to declare a global variable for your new window first. When your button that triggers the ajax request is clicked you open a new window that is referencing to your current domain (https://site1.example.com/ in your case). This is accepted as direct user action, so no popup blocker comes into effect.

In the `complete` function you redirect that window to one of the other domains (https://site1.example2.com or https://site2.example.com), et voilà. I've tested it with activated popup blocker and it worked.

Comment: Is triggered by a click on a button, that fires the Ajax call